# Isn't it possible to use <a> tags in XML just like in HTML?

Tags: html, css, xml

I am just practicing XML. I want to use the `<a>` tag in the XML document to make a link reference to another page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store html tags in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777293/store-html-tags-in-xml)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It has been solved. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be possible with the <a> tag but make sure you use quote marks

So not like this...

```
<a href=pagetwo.html>This goes to page two. But does it?</a>
```

But like this...

```
<a href="pagetwo.html">It works now! We have quote marks!</a>
```

Do be very careful because XML is quite strict about quote marks! Here are some of the rules in XML, for reference. Your code won't work if you don't follow them!

- You need a `<!doctype>`
- You need to put tags in lowercase (`<tExTaReA>` is incorrect)
- You need to end tags properly
- You need to close self-closing tags with a `/`
- Attribute names need to be in lowercase
- **Attributes need to be in quote marks**

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_xhtml.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `a` element in XML like this:

```
<a href="pagetwo.html">Page two</a>
```

But XML doesn't say that this is a link. The semantics of what an `<a>` element means depend entirely on the particular XML vocabulary. This might be a link in one XML vocabulary, and something completely different in another. XML is just syntax.